# If Statement, hide button

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, if-statement, ios7, nsurl

I am trying to evaluate a string for a particular url contained within a dictionary, and then hide the rightbarbutton if that url is the one currently contained in the "url" variable. Using NSLogs, I found that the url string in question is loaded into "url", but the if statement never occurs. I'm a bit of a novice, and would appreciate some feedback on how to appropriately structure this. Thanks a million!

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.webViewDict valueForKey:@"Url"]];
            NSLog(@"%@",url);

if ([url isEqual:@"URLGOESHERE"]){
    NSLog(@"If statement called");
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor   clearColor]}
                                                                      forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
}

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webView loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're comparing an `NSURL` object with an `NSString` object. Of course they will never be equal. You need to do something like this:

```
if([[url absoluteString] isEqualToString:@"http://gacc.nifc.gov/rmcc/predictive/outlook/Rocky_Mountain_Area_Outlook2014.pdf"])
{
// equal!
}
```

Comment: This will be case sensitive compare, you can either use lowercaseString or caseInsensitiveCompare that is part of NSString. NEVER assume correct casing for strings.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing a NSURL with a NSString...

This line:

```
if ([url isEqual:@"URLGOESHERE"])
```

You should probably use [url absoluteString] to compare both values as strings